# Can I use the API to select an edge or face by length / area?

Tags: python, selection-tools

If I want to select all the edges in a mesh which are over 10 units in length, or all faces with area > 10 units, can I do this via the API?

I've looked at [`bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.select_similar) which lets you select features which are similar to the currently-selected feature, so it feels like this should be possible, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using the bmesh module**

This is quite simple with the bmesh module.  Test script selects all faces with area > 10 and all edges with lengths > 10.  Remember these are local coordinates.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

# select faces with area > 10

for f in bm.faces:
    f.select = f.calc_area() > 10

# edges length > 10

for e in bm.edges:
    e.select = e.calc_length() > 10
```